# extract with multiple predicates and multiple predicates

Tags: xpath

I want to extract information from the jms-bus node.  Specifically the busid,

//*[local-name()='jms-bus'][@busid=//*[local-name()='jms-listener']/@busidref]/@busid matches perfectly and returns quickstartGwChannel and quickstartESBChannel if the have matching providers and services.

However, I want to return the jms-bus(s) where it has a jms-listener is-gateway='true'

I am not sure where to put the 'and' clause.  When I put it at the beginning //*[local-name()='jms-listener]/[@is-gateway='true']and ....   it returns a boolean.

I need to extract from this xml

```
<providers>
      <jms-provider name="JBossMQ" connection-factory="ConnectionFactory">
          <jms-bus busid="quickstartGwChannel">
              <jms-message-filter
                  dest-type="QUEUE"
                  dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_gw"
               />
          </jms-bus>
          <jms-bus busid="quickstartEsbChannel">
              <jms-message-filter
                  dest-type="QUEUE"
                  dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb"
              />
          </jms-bus>

      </jms-provider>
  </providers>

  <services>
    <service 
        category="FirstServiceESB" 
        name="SimpleListener" 
        description="Hello World">
        <listeners>
            <jms-listener name="JMS-Gateway"
                busidref="quickstartGwChannel"
                is-gateway="true"
            />
            <jms-listener name="helloWorld"
                          busidref="X12"
                          is-gateway="false"
            />
        </listeners>
        <actions mep="OneWay">
               <action name="action1" 
                class="org.jboss.soa.esb.samples.quickstart.helloworld.MyJMSListenerAction" 
                process="displayMessage" 
                />      
                <action name="action2" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln">
                  <property name="printfull" value="false"/>
                </action>
                <!-- The next action is for Continuous Integration testing -->
                <action name="testStore" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.TestMessageStore"/>
        </actions>
    </service>
  </services>
```

Comment: what are the information you want ..please list down. You xpath is not understandable..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//*[local-name()='jms-bus']
   [@busid=//*[local-name()='jms-listener']
              [@is-gateway='true']/@busidref]/@busid
```

or

```
//*[local-name()='jms-bus']
   [@busid=//*[local-name()='jms-listener' and @is-gateway='true']/@busidref]/@busid
```